# Wrong Total and IIF or Case-When conditon in MDX

Tags: mdx

Let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a Dimension of [Dim Account] which has the attributes like [Account Type],[Account Activity], [Account Marketing] etc. [Account Type] is income, expense,.. [Account Activity] is like Advertising,Discounts, Sale of sponsorship,etc [Account Marketing] is the combination of those things I mean advertising is the expense whereas discounts is stored as the negative income, so ultimately discounts will be treated as marketing expense That's why my member [Negative Total] is converting the income multiplied by -1 and i want to exclude those income are positive as they are income. I want to display only those converted income and finally add up them. In my MDX, the data are displayed perfectly but added up the anonymously due to
the condition of [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All] when I wanted to accumulate with original income (650,920.88) then it's coming up with big figure that's not expected. Another solution I need I want to add up marketing expense(24010.44) with negative marketing income which are already converted (43380.4+9181.32) so finally the result should be 76572.16 like my edited picture. Please modify my MDX.

```
WITH 
  //MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS -- (1)
  //CASE
  //    WHEN ([Measures].[Total],[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]) < 0
  //    THEN [Measures].[Total]*-1
  //    WHEN ([Measures].[Total],[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]) > 0
  //    THEN NULL
  //    ELSE
  //    [Measures].[Total]
  //END
  MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS 
    CASE 
      WHEN 
              [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
            = "Marketing"
          AND 
            [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") = "Income"
        AND 
          [Measures].[Total] < 1 
      THEN 
        [Measures].[Total] * -1
      WHEN 
              [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
            = "Marketing"
          AND 
            [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") = "Income"
        AND 
          [Measures].[Total] > 1 
      THEN NULL
      ELSE 
        [Measures].[Total]
    END 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS 
    CASE 
      WHEN 
          [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CurrentMember
        IS 
          [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All] 
      THEN 
        Sum
        (
          [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS
         ,[Measures].[Negative Total Test]
        )
      ELSE 
        [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
    END 
  //MEMBER [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[TOTAL] AS
  //    [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
  MEMBER [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Total Marketing Expense] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]
      }
     ,[Measures].[Negative Total Test]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Total]
   ,[Measures].[Negative Total]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    (
      {
          [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Type].&[Income]
        * 
          {VisualTotals([Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All])}
       ,
          {
            [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]
           ,[Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
          }
        * 
          [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS
       ,(
          [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Total Marketing Expense]
         ,VisualTotals([Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All])
        )
      }
     ,[Dim Branch].[Trading As].&[BAR]&[Barlens Event Hire]
     ,[Dim Scenario].[Scenario Name].&[Actual]
     ,[Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[December]
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [CubeProfitLoss];
```

Comment: Is there any solution anyone knows? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW ! I got my answers, that's the thing I was looking for. It was nothing but only changes is the display of [Negative Total Test].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2NU4.jpg)

```js
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS
CASE
    WHEN
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing" AND
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") ="Income" AND
        [Measures].[Total]<1
    THEN [Measures].[Total]*-1

    WHEN 
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing" AND
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") ="Income" AND
        [Measures].[Total]>1 
    THEN NULL
 ELSE 
  [Measures].[Total]
END

MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
CASE
 WHEN  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
 THEN 
 SUM(
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS,
        [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
       )
   ELSE [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
END

MEMBER [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Income] AS
 ([Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Type].&[Income], [Measures].[Negative Total])

MEMBER [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Total Marketing Expense] AS
 AGGREGATE
 (
 {
 [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
 ,
 [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing] 
 }
 ,
 [Measures].[Negative Total]
 )

SELECT
 {
 //[Measures].[Total], [Measures].[Negative Total], 
 [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
 } on COLUMNS
 , 
 NON EMPTY 
 (
    {
  (
  [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Type].&[Income]
  * 
  {
  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
  } 
  )
  ,
        (
        {
          [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]
            ,
   [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing] 
        }
        *
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS 
        )
        ,
        (
        [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Total Marketing Expense] 
     ,
  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]  
        )
     } 
 ,
// Traders,
 [Dim Branch].[Trading As].&[BAR]&[Barlens Event Hire] ,
 [Dim Scenario].[Scenario Name].&[Actual]  ,
 [Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[December]
 )
 on ROWS
FROM [CubeProfitLoss]
;
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. This is bad practise `[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing"` you should be using the `IS` operator so something like `[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember  IS [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].[Account Marketing].[Marketing]`